# complexity of std::variant operations

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, time-complexity, variant

In `std::holds_alternative` and `std::get_if` documentation, it does not say what's the complexity requirements of the operations. Are the two functions always `O(1)`, or it's linear in terms of number of types in the `std::variant`? Another way to ask is is there any difference in terms of performance of the two operations on variants that has many member types vs. very few member types.

Comment: Complexity usually only matters when you have a larger and larger input size. How many types do you host in the `std::variant` ?

Comment: it's more than 30 and about 40 types, it's used in busy streaming processing, so i'd like to know the performance implications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most reasonable implementation of a `variant` is an index integer denoting the type (also accessible through the `index()` method) and aligned storage for the held value.

Since the type argument for `holds_alternative` and `get_if` is a template, the type to index computation can be done at compile time. **Therefore the runtime check is performed in const time.** Just a simple integer comparison.

Some variant methods describe time complexity. For example `visit`:

> For n ≤ 1 [n = number of visited variants], the invocation of the callable object is implemented in constant time, i.e., for n = 1, it does not depend on the number of alternative types of `Variants0`. For n > 1, the invocation
> of the callable object has no complexity requirements

This backs up my assessment